# Java Arabic (Hirji) Calendar

Tags: java, mobile, swt, awt

I've been trying to find good international Calendar support (Hirji included) for a mobile app.  My main constraint is that the JVM is 1.3 and we've got AWT only. There is an option to move over to another JVM that gives us SWT, but I can't seem to find any international date pickers for either UI libs. I know Joda-time is available, but looking at the tech docs there doesn't seem to be a UI layer for it. So really, I want to know if anyone has come across a Hirji date picker for AWT or SWT. If not, I'll have to indulge in writing one from scratch :)

I'm pretty sure something is available be it free or commerical as it's hardly a new problem I've stumbled on.

Warmest Regards,

Stephen

Comment: Neither the SWT built-in DateTime control, nor any of the Calendar controls in the SWT Nebula add-on project, implement an Islamic Calendar UI.

Comment: It's beginning to look like I'll need to code one from scratch. Hard to believe this hasn't been done already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joda-time supports Islamic/Hirji Calendar. Find details here: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_islamic.html

Comment: yeah, I know about the Joda-time as I said in my comment, what I'm interested in is there a UI component that gives me the Hirji Calendar view? If not, I'll need to look to doing this from scratch, which is what I want to avoid. Note that I'm limited to AWT and SWT.