# year number convert from gregorian to hijri java time4j

Tags: java, hijri, time4j

I take a year number from user. How can convert it to hijri year number? Better using not jodatime but time4j or java 8.

Example: I need from 2016 to have hijri year number.

I have found this post, [Is there any library or algorithm for Persian (Shamsi or Jalali) calendar in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378764/is-there-any-library-or-algorithm-for-persian-shamsi-or-jalali-calendar-in-and)

```
System.out.println(jalali.transform(PlainDate.class)); // 2015-03-25
```

But method *transform* doesn't work.

Also I have found this post to convert hijri to gregorian:
[Get a gregorian date from Hijri date strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792256/get-a-gregorian-date-from-hijri-date-strings/32330227#32330227)

But I need from gregorian to hijri.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence "*But method transform doesn't work*." should probably be read "*does not compile*".

Reason is that the `HijriCalendar` represents a family of different variants (for example Umalqura). Technical background: This class inherits from `CalendarVariant` instead of `Calendrical`. Therefore the compiler forces you to use a `transform()`-method with [TWO arguments](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/engine/Calendrical.html#transform-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-). The second argument specifies the variant of `HijriCalendar`. Example:

```
PlainDate today = SystemClock.inLocalView().today();

HijriCalendar umalqura = 
  today.transform(HijriCalendar.class, HijriCalendar.VARIANT_UMALQURA);
HijriCalendar westIslamicCivil = 
  today.transform(HijriCalendar.class, HijriAlgorithm.WEST_ISLAMIC_CIVIL);

System.out.println(umalqura); // AH-1437-07-23[islamic-umalqura]
System.out.println(westIslamicCivil); // AH-1437-07-22[islamic-civil]
```

This example also demonstrates why it is important to specify the variant. You see a difference of one day (for the same gregorian date)! Actually Time4J supports 11 variants. The umalquara-variant is the official calendar of Saudi-Arabia while the 8 algorithmic variants should rather be interpreted as approximations and have a wider validity range.

Once you  have an instance of `HijriCalendar` you can easily get the hijri year:

```
int hijriYear = umalqura.getYear();
System.out.println("Year (hirji-umalqura): " + hijriYear); // 1437
```