# Date function getting extra day for Islamic date - Kotlin

Tags: java, android, function, date, kotlin

i have this function to get date:

```
fun getDate() {

    var hijriMonths = resources.getStringArray(R.array.hijri_months)
    val dateFormatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu")
    var sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH)
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    try {
        c.time = sdf.parse(currentDate("dd-MM-yyyy"))
    } catch (e: ParseException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    c.add(
        Calendar.DATE,
        viewModel.days_changed
    )

    var _date: String = sdf.format(c.time)
    val gregorianDate: LocalDate = LocalDate.parse(_date, dateFormatter)
    val islamicDate: HijrahDate = HijrahDate.from(gregorianDate)
    islamic_date.text = islamicDate.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH).toString()+" "+hijriMonths[islamicDate.get(
        ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR
    ) - 1]+" "+islamicDate.get(ChronoField.YEAR) +getString(R.string.hijriSign)

    sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
    try {
        c.time = sdf.parse(currentDate("dd MMMM yyyy"))
    } catch (e: ParseException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    c.add(
        Calendar.DATE,
        viewModel.days_changed
    )
    _date = sdf.format(c.time)
    var day_name = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(c.time)

    date.text = _date
    day.text = day_name

}
```

I'm getting these dates which is correct but the only wrong thing about it is the day of the Islamic date (it add one day) supposed to be 2 no 3 Muharram

[image]

what did i do wrong here?

Comment: Variants of the Islamic calendar exist. Possibly your variant differs from the one used by your software.

Comment: You are mixing old and modern, which is a bad idea and causes needless complication. When you can use the modern `DateTimeFormatter`, `LocalDate` and `HijrahDate`, don’t also mix in the poorly designed and long outdated `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`. The modern API, java.time, gives you all the functionality you need.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, what should i do now?

Comment: Avoid using any date-related classes from the `java.util` package, and stick to the `java.time` package. You can look up tutorials on how to use it.

Comment: I have sort of reproduced. From `HijrahDate.from(LocalDate.of(2021, Month.AUGUST, 11))` I got `Hijrah-umalqura AH 1443-01-03`.

Answer (score 2):

### The problem

Variants of the Islamic calendar exist. They may differ by one or two days on certain dates. The `HijrahDate` class from java.time that I think that you used gives you the Umm al-Qura variant. A likely explanation why your result was a day off is that you expected some other variant.

### Time4J

Other libraries than java.time offer Islamic calendar support. java.time would be my first go-to library, but if it doesn’t offer what you need, it’s probably time to look elsewhere. One possible place to look is the Time4J library. It supports 11 variants of the Islamic calendar, so chances are that it also offers what you need. I am no Android developer myself, and unfortunately I don’t know whether the Android version of Time4J, Time4A, also supports them. As a taste, in the following I am using a couple of the variants.

```
    PlainDate gregorianDate = PlainDate.of(2021, Month.AUGUST, 11);
 
    HijriCalendar diyanet = gregorianDate
            .transform(HijriCalendar.class, HijriCalendar.VARIANT_DIYANET);
    System.out.println(diyanet);

    HijriCalendar westIslamicCivil = gregorianDate
            .transform(HijriCalendar.class, HijriAlgorithm.WEST_ISLAMIC_CIVIL);
    System.out.println(westIslamicCivil);
```

Output is:

> ```
> AH-1443-01-02[islamic-diyanet]
> AH-1443-01-02[islamic-civil]
> ```

So in both cases we got 2 Muharram (not 3).

### Links

- [Time4J - API, Tutorials and Examples](http://time4j.net/)
- [Time4J Releases on GitHub](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J/releases)
- [Time4A on GitHub](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A)
- Related question: [year number convert from gregorian to hijri java time4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953299/year-number-convert-from-gregorian-to-hijri-java-time4j)

Comment: *It supports 11 variants of the Islamic calendar* - This is awesome! I wish `java.time` also had such kind of support.